# How to get discord.py bot to show different stats for every player?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So, I tried to make a currency bot a while back, but it ended up that everyone in the server shared the same amount of currency.

How would I make the users of a bot each have seperate accounts, and not all share the same balance?

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Some dictionary of players to amounts?

Comment: How do I do that? @PatrickHaugh Idk how. Can put a answer with a example?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh please

Comment: A database that you can access through some asynchronous interface.  I've heard good things about `asyncpg`, for Postgres databases.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  yes but i don't have sample code for database setup.  i had asked a question for that still i not received any reply from anyone. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133261/how-to-setup-database-in-python-discord-py

Comment: @PatrickHaugh any idea why it happens like deletes a user data or deletes all users data sometimes. so i can do some changes until connecting to database.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a dictionary of `Member`s to amounts of currency.  I would probably use the member ids, so that you can save the file when you want to shut off your bot.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import json

bot = commands.Bot('!')

amounts = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global amounts
    try:
        with open('amounts.json') as f:             
            amounts = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Could not load amounts.json")
        amounts = {}

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def balance(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.author.id
    if id in amounts:
        await bot.say("You have {} in the bank".format(amounts[id]))
    else:
        await bot.say("You do not have an account")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def register(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.author.id
    if id not in amounts:
        amounts[id] = 100
        await bot.say("You are now registered")
        _save()
    else:
        await bot.say("You already have an account")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def transfer(ctx, amount: int, other: discord.Member):
    primary_id = ctx.message.author.id
    other_id = other.id
    if primary_id not in amounts:
        await bot.say("You do not have an account")
    elif other_id not in amounts:
        await bot.say("The other party does not have an account")
    elif amounts[primary_id] < amount:
        await bot.say("You cannot afford this transaction")
    else:
        amounts[primary_id] -= amount
        amounts[other_id] += amount
        await bot.say("Transaction complete")
    _save()

def _save():
    with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)

@bot.command()
async def save():
    _save()

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/zorin/Desktop/den.py", line 36, in <module>
    async def transfer(ctx, amount: int, other: discord.Member):
NameError: name 'discord' is not defined
 I get error

Comment: @asdwdwdad add `import discord`

Comment: Are you modifying `amounts.json` in any way other than this bot? The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is that if you're using rewrite, your ids will be ints while the ids in the dict will be strings.

Comment: As written, `amounts` an ephemeral `dict` unless you manually invoke `!save`to write it to a file.  It would be trivial to refactor this to move the functionality out of `save` into some other function, and then call that at the end of all the coroutines that modify `amounts`

Comment: @Demotry See the edit I just made.  You can just save the dictionary every time you change it.

Comment: Don't post answers that aren't answers.  If you can't fit something in a comment, it should be it's own question.  That said, you would remove the `with ...` blocks in the `else` and put `_save()` at the end of the outer `else`

Comment: Sure, just check `len(amounts)`

Comment: You could probably make this an instance variable of your cog, `self.amounts`.  If you do, everything that references `amounts` must go in that cog.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  what do i need to add if i need to get top 10 members with highest amounts.

Comment: make `amounts` a `Counter` then use `Counter.most_common(10)`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  how to make counter ?  does it shows recent users or  high amount users list.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter