# Referring to a member as a variable in Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot that runs chat filter; my end goal is for a bot to have a list of words and if one of those words from the list is said, the bot will add a tally to a member and if they get like 3 then a command to kick from server will run.

Creating the list is easy and I know how to write the command to kick someone, but I am absolutely lost on how I would get the bot to track values for each member.... Would I need to set the member's ID as a variable?

Any help is appreciated, I am just absolutely stuck and have limited experience in the discord.py module.

```
import asyncio
import json
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='#')

infractions = {}
blacklist = ["bad", "word"]
limit = 5


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global infractions
    try:
        with open('infractions.json') as f:
            infractions = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Could not load infractions.json")
        infractions = {}


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content.lower()
    if any(word in content for word in blacklist):
        id = message.author.id
        infractions[id] = infractions.get(id, 0) + 1
        if infractions[id] >= limit:
            await bot.kick(message.author)
        else:
            warning = f"{message.author.mention} this is your {infractions[id]} warning"
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, warning)
    await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command()
async def save():
    with open('infractions.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(infractions, f)
```

Comment: You have two `on_ready` events. You should consolidate them. Are you seeing an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a dictionary of member ids to number of infractions.  You can get the id from the `message.author.id` attribute

```
from discord.ext import commands

infractions = {}
blacklist = ["bad", "word"]
limit = 5

bot = commands.Bot('!')    

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content.lower()
    if any(word in content for word in blacklist):
        id = message.author.id
        infractions[id] = infractions.get(id, 0) + 1
        if infractions[id] >= limit:
            await bot.kick(message.author)
        else:
            warning = f"{message.author.mention} this is your {infractions[id]} warning"
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, warning)
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

I suggest using ids as keys rather than `Member` objects so that you can more easily save the file as a JSON, which will allow you to persist values when you shut off your bot.  [See this other answer I wrote for an example of how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890310/how-to-get-discord-py-bot-to-show-different-stats-for-every-player/50901369#50901369)

Comment: That was way more helpful of an answer then I expected... Thank you so much

Comment: Can you please help me with saving the values.. I looked at your answer but i dont really understand how it works. Thank you!

Comment: The idea is that you use the `json.load` to read a file into a dictionary in the `on_ready` event, and save to file with `json.dump` (You should glance through the documentation for these functions, but we don't use any of the fancy stuff).  Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def save(ctx):
    with open('infractions.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(infractions, f)

This is my code but nothing saves..?

Comment: I bet it's [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working) because we have an `on_message` and commands.  I'll update the code here to account for that.

Comment: hmm. still not working for me... is there anyway I can share my code with you by like a screen shot for example so u can actually see the code in a non messy way?

Comment: You can make a new question, copy-paste the code into the body of the question, then highlight it and press ctrl-k to format it.

Comment: You can edit it into the body of your question here then