# Bot won't respond and also won't give me any errors

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I've recently switched to a client to bot as I've been told it a lot better than using the client. I asked a question a few weeks ago about a text-based game you can see it here [How to use commands only when a current command is triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51112373/how-to-use-commands-only-when-a-current-command-is-triggered/51119889?noredirect=1#comment89452505_51119889)

Somebody gave me an example of my question however the code doesn't work for some reason. All of my other commands work fine.

```
    class Game:
def __init__(self):
    self.points = 0
    self.inventory = []
sessions = {}
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx):
if ctx.message.author.id in sessions:
    await bot.say("You're already playing")
    return
sessions[ctx.message.author.id] = Game()
await bot.say("Welcome to the game!")
```

Comment: Please double check your indentation, it's important in python.  Is this the entirety of your code?  Are you doing `bot.run("TOKEN")` at the end? Are you seeing any errors in the console when you try to invoke the command?

Comment: No this is not my entire code you can check my entire code on github (https://github.com/CakeCode123/Cakebot/blob/master/bot.py) 

and yes i think i have my indentation correct and i also have 'bot.run("token)' there you can double check it if i'm wrong.