# How to Setup Database in Python Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello I'm new to this database setup i don't know anything about database setup in python bot. I decided to add a database connection to my Postgresql account which i been created newly to store user data.

So can i get any example full code to setup Postgresql database account.

---

Update this is my file code.

```
token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
prefix = "!"

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import csv

startup_extensions = ["xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx"]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('\nLogged in as')
    print("Bot Name: " + bot.user.name)
    print("Bot User ID: " + bot.user.id)


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content = message.content.lower()
    await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for extension in startup_extensions:
        try:
            bot.load_extension(extension)
        except Exception as e:
            exc = '{}: {}'.format(type(e).__name__, e)
            print('Failed to load extension {}\n{}'.format(extension, exc))

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Still no answer from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Read the asyncpg documentation, that's about it.
Your Question is not clear enough as to "setup Postgresql database account" is not a Python or discord.py issue.