# Making a variable for discord bot that doesn't get reset if the bot goes down

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I started making a discord bot in python. What I want to do is set up a system of points for all the members of the server.

I have a "game" already set up where you guess a number from 0-9 and if it's correct, it will say "correct". What I need is to set up a points variable for each person on the server, so each person could play. I could set point variables at the top of my file, but then it would reset back to 0 whenever I restart the bot. Maybe I can save it all to a text file and read from that?

```
    if message.content.startswith('!gamble'):
    if len(message.content) != 9:
        msg = 'Improper command form' + str(len(message.content))
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
        return

    num = randint(0,9)
    guess = message.content[8]
    if str(num) == str(guess):
        msg = 'You win! You guessed ' + str(guess) + ' and the number was ' + str(num)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

    else:
        msg = 'You lost :(. You guessed ' + str(guess) + ' and the number was ' + str(num)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

This part works correctly. I could easily add a variable at the top and add a point every time someone is correct, but then it would go back to whatever it was set to. How would you recommend going about this?

Comment: [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890310/how-to-get-discord-py-bot-to-show-different-stats-for-every-player/50901369#50901369) I wrote of a very similar program.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write it to a text file.

There is no way to save persistent variables in Python (or any programming languages in my knowledge) because programs are loaded into the computer's RAM when they are run. This ram is allocated for your program by the operating system, which also takes back all the ram once your program has finished running, therefore, no data is preserved for the next run.

If you are only going to be using Python for this project, I would suggest looking into the `pickle` module for an easy solution. More info here: [Python 3.7.2 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), [Python 2.7.15 docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create any variables like this one. The best (I think) solution for this problem will be using a DataBase. There are lot's of them to choose. Here are 2 examples,
[MySql](https://www.mysql.com/) and [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/).