# Updating Dict in File

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a Python Discord bot for a server I'm a part of and one of the features the owners asked for is a command that will return the age of a user. I've managed to add it to file and then read that file and get good results. But whenever I attempt to add more users to the dictionary, it just adds a new dictionary into the file and messes everything up.

```
users_age = {}

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def addAge(ctx, member : discord.Member, age : int):
    users_age[str(member.mention)] = age
    fh = open('age.txt', 'a')
    fh.write(str(users_age))
    await bot.say("File written successfully!")
    fh.close()

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def Age(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    users_age = eval(open('age.txt', 'r').read())
    await bot.say(users_age[str(member.mention)])
```

Comment: Augh, don't use `eval`, it's evil.

Comment: Using `eval()` is the only way I've gotten it to work properly. I get `TypeError` otherwise.

Comment: The problem is you are using `fh.write(str(users_age))` and pretending it is serialization. It is *not*. Use a built-in text-based serialization format, like JSON with the `json` module.

Comment: You can see one way of persisting a dictionary to a json file from a discord bot in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890310/how-to-get-discord-py-bot-to-show-different-stats-for-every-player/50901369#50901369

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [built-in `shelve` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) for a simple database you don't have to manage by hand.

It smells, API-wise, like a dictionary, but is actually backed by a file on the disk.

```
import shelve


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def addAge(ctx, member: discord.Member, age: int):
    with shelve.open("ages") as age_db:
        age_db[str(member.mention)] = age
    await bot.say("File written successfully!")


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def Age(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    with shelve.open("ages") as age_db:
        age = age_db.get(str(member.mention))
    if age is not None:
        await bot.say(age)
    else:
        await bot.say("I don't know.")
```